# How to Make Product Weight Attribute searchable in magento2.4.2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.2

Hello I am using magento2.4.2 in that when i try to enable Product Weight Attribute the search filed is stop to work and i got below error in exception, i want Product weight attribute searchable.

[image: Exception.log]
[image]

Comment: have you did indexing after changes in attribute??

Comment: @GohilRajesh Yes i done that and there is the fresh magento